# Proof that measurable functions are dense in $\mathcal{L}^{\infty}$ in Measure Theory of Cohn

Tags: integration, measure-theory

I'm reading the book Measure Theory (second edition) from Donald L.Cohn and
have a problem in understanding his proof that the set of measurable simple
functions form a dense subset of $\mathcal{L}^{\infty} [X, \mathcal{A}, \mu]$
(Proposition 3.4.2. Page 100). In this proof the following definitions are
used:

$\mathcal{L}^{\infty} [X, \mathcal{A}, \mu]$ is the set of all real valued
bounded functions.

$\| f \|_{\infty} = \inf \{ M \in [0, \infty [| \{ x \in X| | f (x) | > M \}
$ is a locally null set }.

$N \subseteq X$ is locall null if $\forall A\in\mathcal{A}$ with $\mu (A) < \infty$ we
have $\mu \left( A \bigcap N \right) = 0$.

In the proof for $f \in \mathcal{L}^{\infty} [X, \mathcal{A}, \mu]$ he find
real numbers $a_0, \ldots, a_n$ such that $a_0 < a_1 < \cdots < a_n$, the
intervals $] a_{i - 1}, a_i]$ covers $[- \| f \|_{\infty}, \| f \|_{\infty}]$
and have length less then $\varepsilon$. He then constructs the simple
measurable function $f_{\varepsilon} = \sum_{i = 1}^n a_i \cdot
\mathcal{X}_{A_i}$ where $A_i = f^{- 1} (] a_{i - 1}, a_i])$. So far I can
follow the construction and can proof that $f_{\varepsilon}$ is indeed
measurable. However next he says that $\| f - f_{\varepsilon} \|_{\infty} <
\varepsilon$ which I fail to understand. If $x \in \bigcup_{i = 1}^n A_i$ then
there exists a $i \in \{ 1, \ldots, n \}$ such that $a_{i - 1} < f (x)
\leqslant a_i$ so that $| f (x) - f_{\varepsilon} (x) | < \varepsilon$ but
what about the case of $x \in X\backslash \bigcup_{i = 1}^n A_i$? Somehow I
fail to understand that $\| f - f_{\varepsilon} \|_{\infty} < \infty$.

Thanks in advance for any help or link.

I think I have found the answer to my question. As $X\backslash \bigcup_{i =
1}^n A_i = \{ x \in X| | f (x) | > \| f \|_{\infty} \}$ and it is proved in
the book that $\| f \|_{\infty} \in \left\{ M \in [0, \infty [| \{ x \in X|f
(x) > M \} \text{ is a locally null set} \right\}$, it follows that
$X\backslash \bigcup_{i = 1}^n A_i$ is a locally null set. If now $x \in \{ x
\in X| | f (x) - f_{\varepsilon} (x) | > \varepsilon \}$ then $x \in
X\backslash [- \| f \|_{\infty}, \| f \|_{\infty}]$ [otherwise $| f (x) -
f_{\varepsilon} (x) | < \varepsilon$ as I have already shown in my question].
So $\{ x \in X| | f (x) - f_{\varepsilon} (x) | > \varepsilon \} \subseteq
X\backslash \bigcup_{i = 1}^n A_i$ proving that $\{ x \in X| | f (x) -
f_{\varepsilon} (x) | > \varepsilon \}$ is a locally null set. Hence
$\varepsilon \in \left\{ M \in [0, \infty [| \{ x \in X| | f (x) -
f_{\varepsilon} (x) | > M \} \text{ is a locally null set} \right\}$, which
proves that $\| f - f_{\varepsilon} \|_{\infty} = \inf \left\{ M \in [0,
\infty [| \{ x \in X| | f (x) - f_{\varepsilon} (x) | > M \} \text{ is a
locally null set} \right\} \leqslant \varepsilon$. So $\| f - f_{\varepsilon}
\|_{\infty} \leqslant \varepsilon$.

The only problem that I see is that in the book $\| f - f_{\varepsilon}
\|_{\infty} < \varepsilon$ instead of $\| f - f_{\varepsilon} \| \leqslant
\varepsilon$, but this is not a problem if we have to prove densitiy.

It this a correct proof or did I forget something?

Comment: $\mathcal{L}^{\infty} [X, \mathcal{A}, \mu]$ is the set of all [...] *sets*?

Comment: The set $X\setminus\bigcup^n_{j=1}A_j$ has local measure zero.

Comment: "$\forall N \in A$"? Rather $\forall A\in \mathcal A.$